# Best way to remove element from Ruby hash array in yaml

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, yaml

I see a lot online about removing *keys* from yaml, but not much on removing a element from a hash array (maybe I'm searching on the wrong concept?). Sorry, I'm pretty new to Ruby or any programming for that matter.

I'm trying to remove a specific port from the yaml file without actually deleting the IP itself or any of the rest of its array value.

```
require 'yaml'
ip = 1.2.3.4
port = 3333

hash = YAML.load_file('ips.yml')
hash.delete([ip][port])
File.open('ips.yml','w'){|f| YAML.dump(hash,f)}
```

yaml file

```
---
69.39.239.151:
- 7777
- 8677
- 8777
69.39.239.75:
- 9677
- 9377
209.15.212.147:
- 8477
- 7777
104.156.244.109:
- 9999
1.2.3.4:
- 3333
- 4444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'yaml'
ip = '1.2.3.4'
port = 3333

hash = YAML.load_file('ips.yml')
puts "hash (before): #{hash.inspect}"
hash[ip].delete(port) # here you are deleting the port (3333) from the ip (1.2.3.4)
puts "hash (after): #{hash.inspect}"
File.open('ips.yml', 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(hash, f) }

# hash (before): {"69.39.239.151"=>[7777, 8677, 8777], "69.39.239.75"=>[9677, 9377], "209.15.212.147"=>[8477, 7777], "104.156.244.109"=>[9999], "1.2.3.4"=>[3333, 4444]}
# hash (after): {"69.39.239.151"=>[7777, 8677, 8777], "69.39.239.75"=>[9677, 9377], "209.15.212.147"=>[8477, 7777], "104.156.244.109"=>[9999], "1.2.3.4"=>[4444]}
```

Comment: This solution works but I lost all the comments in yaml :-(